# Measuring network bandwidth usage

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machines, bandwidth, wireshark

One VM is sending data to another VM using `rsync`, both VMs are hosted on the same machine. I've got the task to measure the network bandwidth usage between both VMs and plot it.

Plotting is easy once the data is captured, so the problem is to capture the network bandwidth usage for a time series. How to do this?

**EDIT:** I'll try other answers also but due to short deadline, i came across wireshark tool, and is able to see I/O graphs on VM2, But how would i see graphs which will only show `rsync` traffic from VM1 to VM2?

Answer (score 3):

There are a tonne of options for monitoring bandwidth usage on Linux, one very quick one that springs to mind is [bmon](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bmon). This is a very easy program to use and install with a nice interface.

There are more however:

- nload
- iftop
- iptraf
- tcptrack
  (*to name a few*)

If you're however looking for a more long term, permanent solution then I would personally use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) + [Node Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) and [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) for visualization - [a simple guide to get you going](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/configure-prometheus-monitoring-with-grafana/).